# Is it possible to pass query parameters in the request body for Clickhouse's http interface?

Tags: clickhouse

According to the [docs](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/http/), the Clickhouse's http interface allows me to pass query parameters in a query string like this:

First, I can write a query with a parameter:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = {id:text}
```

This query is passed in the body request, and the value for id is passed in the query string as follows:

```
http://clickhouse-host:8123/param_id=1
```

However, I wonder if there's a way to pass both the query and its parameters in the body request. I could not find how to achieve this in the docs.

Comment: not implemented yet https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/8842

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since it has not been implemented yet, I will favor a client that uses the regular TCP interface for now.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8123/?param_size=100' -d "SELECT * FROM numbers({size:UInt32})"
```